# R: Aggregating by date and hour and placing into a separate matrix

Tags: r, date, aggregate

I am looking to take a dataframe which has data ordered through time and aggregate up to the hourly level, and place the data into a separate dataframe. It's best explained with an example:

tradeData dataframe:

```
Time                     Amount  
2014-05-16 14:00:05       10  
2014-05-16 14:00:10       20  
2014-05-16 14:08:15       30  
2014-05-16 14:23:09       51  
2014-05-16 14:59:54       84  
2014-05-16 15:09:45       94  
2014-05-16 15:24:41       53  
2014-05-16 16:30:51       44
```

The matrix above contains the data I would like to aggregate. Below is the dataframe into which I would like to insert it:
HourlyData dataframe:

```
Time                        Profit  
2014-05-16 00:00:00          100  
2014-05-16 01:00:00          200  
2014-05-16 02:00:00          250  
...  
2014-05-16 14:00:00           30  
2014-05-16 15:00:00          -50   
2014-05-16 16:00:00           67  
...  
2014-05-16 23:00:00           -8
```

I would like to aggregate the data in the tradeData dataframe and place it in the correct place in the hourlyData dataframe as below:
New hourlyData dataframe:

```
Time                        Profit   Amount
2014-05-16 00:00:00          100         0
2014-05-16 01:00:00          200         0
2014-05-16 02:00:00          250         0
...  
2014-05-16 14:00:00           30         0
2014-05-16 15:00:00          -50       195 (10+20+30+51+84)  
2014-05-16 16:00:00           67       147 (94+53)
2014-05-16 17:00:00           20        44
...  
2014-05-16 23:00:00           -8         0
```

Using the solution provided by Akrun below, I was able to get a solution for most instances. However, there appears to be an issue when an event occurs within the last hour of the day, as below:
TradeData

```
        Time            Amount
2014-08-15 22:09:07     11037.778
2014-08-15 23:01:33     13374.724
2014-08-20 23:25:40     133373.000
```

HourlyData

```
  Time                  Amount
2014-08-15 23:00:00     11037.778 (correct)    
2014-08-18 00:00:00         0 (incorrect)  
2014-08-21 00:00:00     133373 (correct)
```

The formula appears to be skip the data for the second trade in the tradeData dataframe when aggregating in the hourlyData dataframe. It appears as though this occurs for trades that occur in the last hour of a Friday,because (I imagine) data doesn't exist for a Saturday at 12am i.e. Friday 11PM + 1 hour. It works for a trade occurring in the last hour of Monday to Thursday.

Any ideas on how to adjust the algo? Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Thanks

Mike

Comment: DO you need to aggregate by date and hour or just hour?

Comment: By date AND hour. Will edit the question

Comment: Yes, just put it through now. Thanks so much for all your help, appreciate it!

Comment: No problem.  It seems like the feature was added in the new devel version

Comment: I updated the solution.  Hope it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
res <- left_join(df2,
                   df %>% 
                     group_by(hour=as.POSIXct(cut(Time, breaks='hour'))+3600) %>% 
                     summarise(Amount=sum(Amount)),
                      by=c('Time'='hour'))

res$Amount[is.na(res$Amount)] <- 0
res
#                     Time Profit Amount
#1 2014-05-16 00:00:00    100       0
#2 2014-05-16 01:00:00    200       0
#3 2014-05-16 02:00:00    250       0
#4 2014-05-16 14:00:00     30       0
#5 2014-05-16 15:00:00    -50     195
#6 2014-05-16 16:00:00     67     147
#7 2014-05-16 23:00:00     -8       0
```

Or using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 DT <- data.table(df)
 DT2 <- data.table(df2)
 DT1 <- DT[,list(Amount=sum(Amount)), by=(Time=
               as.POSIXct(cut(Time, breaks='hour'))+3600)]
 setkey(DT1, Time)
 DT1[DT2][is.na(Amount), Amount:=0][]
 #                      Time Amount Profit
 #1: 2014-05-16 00:00:00      0    100
 #2: 2014-05-16 01:00:00      0    200
 #3: 2014-05-16 02:00:00      0    250
 #4: 2014-05-16 14:00:00      0     30
 #5: 2014-05-16 15:00:00    195    -50
 #6: 2014-05-16 16:00:00    147     67
 #7: 2014-05-16 23:00:00      0     -8
```

#### Update

Based on the weekends info,

```
 indx <- with(df, as.numeric(format(Time, '%H'))==23 & 
           as.numeric(format(Time, '%S'))>0& format(Time, '%a')=='Fri')
 grp <- with(df, as.POSIXct(cut(Time, breaks='hour')))
 grp[indx] <- grp[indx] +3600*49
 grp[!indx] <- grp[!indx]+3600

 df$Time <- grp
 df %>%
    group_by(Time) %>% 
    summarise(Amount=sum(Amount)) #in the example dataset, it is just 3 rows
 #                 Time    Amount
 #1 2014-08-15 23:00:00  11037.78
 #2 2014-08-18 00:00:00  13374.72
 #3 2014-08-21 00:00:00 133373.00
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(Time = structure(c(1400263205, 1400263210, 1400263695, 
 1400264589, 1400266794, 1400267385, 1400268281, 1400272251), class = c("POSIXct", 
 "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Amount = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 51L, 84L, 94L, 
 53L, 44L)), .Names = c("Time", "Amount"), row.names = c(NA, -8L
 ), class = "data.frame")

 df2 <- structure(list(Time = structure(c(1400212800, 1400216400, 1400220000, 
 1400263200, 1400266800, 1400270400, 1400295600), class = c("POSIXct", 
 "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Profit = c(100L, 200L, 250L, 30L, -50L, 
 67L, -8L)), .Names = c("Time", "Profit"), row.names = c(NA, -7L
 ), class = "data.frame")
```

#### newdata

```
 df <- structure(list(Time = structure(c(1408158000, 1408334400, 1408593600
 ), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Amount = c(11037.778, 
 13374.724, 133373)), .Names = c("Time", "Amount"), row.names = c(NA, 
 -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Looks perfect, thanks so much! Not able to implement it just yet, but will let you know when I try it out. Thanks again!

Comment: hi. I've just been trying to get the above code to work, but I keep getting the following error: `Error: cannot join on columns 'hour' x 'Time' : index out of bounds`. I've checked, and every time entry in df exists in df2, so I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: @Mike `by=c('Time'='hour'))` works on  `dplyr_0.3` or else change `group_by(hour=as.POSIXct` to `group_by(Time=as.POSIXct(` and use `by='Time'`

Comment: I'm having a bit of difficulty with the above solution. It seems as though when something is traded at, say 2014-08-15 23:01:33 (the last hour on a Friday), the amount isn't recorded on 2014-08-18 00:00:00. It seems to just skip the number completely. Is there any way around this? It seems to work perfectly for all other instances. Thanks!

Comment: @Mike Is it `2014-08-15 00:00:00` or `08-18`?  Also, could you consider providing an example or perhaps a new post with this

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. It is 2014-08-18 00:00:00 I will provide an example in the question above